# How do I pass data from page content to the underlying PHP template

Tags: pages, templates, page-template

Pretty much all of the content on the site is going to be dynamically generated (php + db backend)

What is the preferred "wordpress way" of passing data to a php template (set up as a template in a wordpress theme)

So the template would be something like

```
<?php

generate_content_based_on_this_variable(page);

?>
```

and I'd need to be able to pass it `page` for each different page

---

Edit 1

So I have a page that, for simplicity, looks something like this

> Hi everyone, this is page X The content here is generated from a db call:
>
> SELECT * FROM db WHERE page=X
>
> [Spit out db resultset here]

and the template would be something like

```
<?php

the_content()

$query='SELECT * FROM db WHERE page=X'
$result=$db->execute($query)
foreach($result as $row){
echo $row
}

?>
```

Comment: 1. What is the 'template'? Is it a html skeleton that is later filled with content generated by php?

Comment: 2. What sort of content are you displaying on your pages? Is it articles (posts) or some other type of content that cannot be produced by the regular WordPress posts mechanism?

Comment: Its basically a dump of a db table (for now)
The template is actually a custom template -- I copied the source from template:squirrel/page.php and added in some db statements after the `the_content()` call

Comment: Basically a lot of the (nonstatic) content has to be generated in php. Ideally, I'd just want a wordpress shell (to manage users/styles/comments and such) with PHP content in place of all the static 'posts'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to produce a page in WordPress whose structure and content are dynamically generated independent of the regular posts handling mechanism then:

1. Create a new page with title "**My Custom Page**". This generates the page slug '`my-custom-page`' by default.
2. In the root of your active theme folder eg. *\wp-content\themes\twentyeleven\* create a page template for this new page named `page-my-custom-page.php`.
3. Put your custom php code inside the page template.
4. Navigate to **your-site.com/my-custom-page/** to see the results

Comment: So this is similar to what I have already done (create a page based on a custom PHP template). My question is, can I create several more pages based on the same template such that each page pulls different info from the database

Comment: Yes. You simply pass a query argument to the page (eg. your-site.com/my-custom-page/?thepage=2) and then it picks data based on the value of the query argument.

Comment: I want it to be more like mysite.com/pageX and mysite.com/pageY where the variable would be hardcoded in on the backend. PageX calls loads the template with argument 'X' whereas PageY loads it with argument 'Y'

Comment: In that case you might want to look into wp_rewrite. It does a good job of handling custom urls

Comment: Is there no way in WP just to have it do something like URL routing (/page/:id style) or use a render template or partial views or anything?

Comment: Do you mean this sort of thing: your-site.com/my-custom-page/2. That is exactly what wp_rewrite handles. Another approach is to follow the BuddyPress model. It requires less ongoing maintenance, but is really tough to setup.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking a pretty vague question, but I think you should check out the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), it might help you get a better understanding of how WordPress behaves.

You can use page-$slug.php or page-$id.php to automatically include a page-specific template.

Comment: Yeah, I already found that through google.

Comment: I mean, I have a page that's based off of a template. But that template needs to change its db query based on which page is being loaded

Comment: @arcyqwerty Huh? So confused.

Comment: So I have created a page and a template. The page uses this template but needs to tell the template code what to query from the database

Comment: I'll edit question